# onmousedown event is not giving continuous event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want user mouse position while the user is holding down the mouse button continuously?

I try to do the with following code:

```
$(div).mousedown(function(eventObj){
    console.log(eventObj.clientX);  
});
```

but this code is giving mouse position only once when the user presses the mouse button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to put the mousemove event into the mousedown event so that when the mousedown event triggers the mousemove event that fires continously also fires. This allows the mouse location to be tracked when the mouse button is held down. The mouseup event was added so that on release it stops tracking the mouse location from the mousemove event.

https://jsfiddle.net/q37z3g94/

```
$(
```

```
"#test").mousedown(function(eventObj) {
  $("#test").mousemove(function(event) {
    var pageCoords = "( " + event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY + " )";
    var clientCoords = "( " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY + " )";
    $("span:first").text("( event.pageX, event.pageY ) : " + pageCoords);
    $("span:last").text("( event.clientX, event.clientY ) : " + clientCoords);
  });
});

$("#test").mouseup(function(eventObj) {
  $("#test").unbind('mousemove');
});
```

Comment: Edited per request. My first answer so I guess I just forgot that someone that may get to the page may need a better explanation of what that code does. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

For example, you could use the `setInterval` function to repeatedly call a function while the **mouse button is down**, and then use `clearInterval` to stop when the mouse button is released. Here is an example (using jQuery):

```
var interval;
$("#div").mousedown(function(eventObj) {
    interval = setInterval(performWhileMouseDown(eventObj), 100);
}).mouseup(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);  
});
function performWhileMouseDown(eventObj) {
    console.log(eventObj.clientX);
}
```

Comment: yeah, the benefit to this is that it will fire even when the mouse isn't moving.

Answer (score 1):

You could use mousedown and mouseup to set a flag - maybe `isMouseDown`, and then you can use clientX and clientY with that info where you need it

Comment: Sorry, that wouldn't be fully continuous but depending on the application could still be useful.

Comment: Well, that does work. See my example. I use the mousedown/mouseup to set the isDragging boolean, then the mouseMove to do something if I have a true value for isDragging. It allows you to simulate mousedrag events.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the `onMouseMove` event. What you should do is `onMouseDown` start listening to the `onMouseMove` event with what you want done, then `onMouseUp` stop listening. Example code would look like:

```
$(div).mousedown(function(eventObj){
    $(div).mousemove(function(evt){
        console.log(''+evt.pageX+', '+evt.pageY);
    });  
});
$(div).mouseup(function(eventObj){
    $(div).off( "mousemove" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of simulating the mousedrag event. Basically, on mouseDown the isDragging boolean is set to true, then in the mouseMove I check to see if isDragging, and if so, do something. On mouseUp, I set the isDragging back to false. Easiest way I've found.

```js
var isDragging = false;
/***
 * Tracking the dragging -- on mousedown, I set
 *   the isDragging to true, then I check that for
 *   the mousemove on this element.
 *   - On mouseup, I reset the isDragging to false,
 *     thus ending the simulated drag event.
 ***/
$(".slide-control").on("mousemove", function(evt) {
  if (isDragging) {
    console.log(evt.pageX+", "+evt.pageY);
  }
}).on("mouseup", function() {
  // When the drag event has ended, set the toggle off.
  isDragging = false;
}).on("mousedown", function() {
  isDragging = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-control"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p>

<p>Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Proin eget tortor risus.</p></div>
```

Another option, a little late to the ballgame, is to create your own custom event. This would allow you to actually use something like:
    $(".my-custom-el").on("mousedrag", function(){...});

To do this, simply define the trigger for this custom event, like so:

```js
/****
 * Here I'm using the custom event I've created.
 *   As there are multiple elements side-by-side, 
 *   depending on which event triggers causes a
 *   different result. Change the downEvt to the
 *   dragEvt in the following function to see what
 *   happens.
 ****/
$(".sub-pane").on("mousedrag", function(evt){
  console.log($(this).prop("id")+", dragging");
});


/*****
 * This function is a custom event, could be placed
 *  in a utility library someplace. It simply listens
 *  at the document level for a combination of mouse
 *  down and mouse move, and when that occurs, it
 *  triggers a mousedrag event. Now, the event target
 *  used to trigger the event can be either the 
 *  mousedown element OR the mousemove element. 
 *  - Using the downEvt.target to trigger the event
 *    will continue to trigger the event ONLY on its
 *    starting element, even if you drag over another
 *    element.
 *  - using the dragEvt.target to trigger will 
 *    use the element you're currently over as the
 *    triggered element.
 *****/
$(document).on("mousedown", function(downEvt){
  $(document).on("mousemove", function(moveEvt){
    return $(downEvt.target).trigger("mousedrag");
  });
});
```

```css
.nav-pane {
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  float: left;
}
.content-pane {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
}
.nav-pane ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  left: -25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  <div id="pane-one" class="sub-pane nav-pane">
    <ul>
      <li>first</li>
      <li>second</li>
      <li>third</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="pane-two" class="sub-pane content-pane">
    <p>Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed,
      convallis at tellus.</p>

    <p>Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet
      et, porttitor at sem. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this approach is that the event is constantly firing. In my solution the mousemove event only fires when the mouse button is pressed. While not likely to have a performance influence, on a page with a lot of events and things it could do something. Mostly just principle though.

Comment: true, it is constantly firing -- but the reality is, it's constantly firing anyway. If you're using jQuery, the trigger is being fired. I simply check each time and only intercept it if the boolean is set. It's a matter of preference, but I see the value of both.

Comment: The function you write isn't being fired unless it's registered. True the browser has to be doing something to check if functions are hooked to that event, but that's not creating a javacsript call stack etc. The browser isn't written in JS, thus that happens a lot faster.

Comment: There is no value in having the event listener constantly running, unless you also want movement updated when the mouse button isn't pressed, then there's no avoiding it.

Comment: As I said, I see the value of your approach. I'm simply not a fan of nesting the mousemove call inside the mousedown, but that's just me. Reality is, either approach is kludgy. We're simply debating which is the less kludgy approach. Speaking purely subjectively... nah.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with binding events inside of other events, but live in your bliss I suppose.

Comment: I don't say there's anything wrong with it, said I'm simply not a fan.